# What does Party Member Affection do?

Tags: .hack-gu, .hack-gu-last-recode

in *.hack//G.U Vol. 2 Reminiscence* one can easily see the effect of a party member's affection for you when you use Divine Awakening as the color of the bar you stop the cursor at determines the attack.

But in *.hack//G.U Vol. 3 Redemption* Divine Awakening is changed to Avatar Awakening and it's damage is determined by it's own level (which increases as you use it more) and i don't recall what effect, if any, affection had on Beast or Demon in regards to awakenings.

so aside from Divine Awakening, what does Party Member Affection do? i am also asking about any new features added in *.hack//G.U Vol. 4 Reconnection* (as the previous 3 volumes always added something new before *Last Recode*)